# Long/Integer modulus operations v.s BigInteger operations in Java

Tags: java, integer, biginteger, modulus

I'm working on a powermod function and getting some odd results, perhaps someone could help explain what I'm seeing...

```
int a = 2147483647
int b = Integer.MAX_VALUE
int m = 3
long _A = (long) a;
BigInteger A = BigInteger.valueOf(a);
BigInteger M = BigInteger.valueOf(m);
// Compute with BigInteger  
int x = A.multiply(A).mod(M).intValue();
//compute with long
int y = (int) ((_A*_A) %m);
assert x ==y ; // is false?
```

Comment: Outputting the values of each operation should tell you what's going on.

Comment: What are the values involved?

Comment: Looks fine to me: http://ideone.com/wICtoR.